# Проблема считывания чисел из консоли

Tags: java

В программе считывается массив чисел. Должны выводиться числа, кратные 3.

```java
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Main {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            int length = getLengthOfArray();
            double [] arrayOfNumbers = getElementsOfArray(length);
            searchElementsOfArray(arrayOfNumbers);
        }

        private static int getLengthOfArray() {
            int length;
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Please, enter a length of array: ");
            do {
                while (!sc.hasNextInt()) {
                    System.out.println("Invalid value entered. Please, try again:");
                    sc.next();
                }
                length = sc.nextInt();
                if (length <= 0) {
                    System.out.println("You must enter a positive number. Please, try again:");
                }
            } while (length <= 0);
            sc.close();
            return length;
        }

        private static double [] getElementsOfArray(int length) {
            double [] arrayOfNumbers = new double [length];
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Please, enter an element of array: ");
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                while (!sc.hasNextDouble()) {
                    System.out.println("Invalid value entered. Please, try again:");
                    sc.next();
                }
                arrayOfNumbers [i] = sc.nextDouble();
            }
            return arrayOfNumbers;
        }

        private static void searchElementsOfArray(double [] arrayOfNumbers) {
            for (double arrayOfNumber : arrayOfNumbers) {
                if (arrayOfNumber % 3 == 0) {
                    System.out.print(arrayOfNumber);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Результат запуска программы:

```
Please, enter a length of array: 3
Please, enter an element of array: 
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:937)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2564)
    at task3.Main.getElementsOfArray(Main.java:40)
    at task3.Main.main(Main.java:9)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Почему возникает эта ошибка?

Comment: Как понимаю, минусы из-за того, что код не минимальный, хотя такое тут не редкость. Или нужно было чуть подробней описать проблему, хотя стек ошибки ты сразу приложил. Наверно, проверки можно было бы убрать в рамках вопроса. Не нашел других причин для минусов. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic
Вообще, не понимаю людей, ставящих минусы без объяснения причин, особенно у новичков

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема возникает из-за того, что ты закрываешь входной поток (на чтение), а потом пытаешься читать из него. Если не закрывать `scanner`, работает нормально. Проверил [тут](https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_java_compiler). Как понимаю, закрывая `Scanner sc`, ты одновременно закрываешь `System.in`, и из него больше нельзя считать.

Это подтверждается на сайте Oracle по [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html):

> When a Scanner is closed, it will close its input source if the source implements the Closeable interface.

Полное решение (добавил пробел между числами):

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int length = getLengthOfArray();
        double [] arrayOfNumbers = getElementsOfArray(length);
        searchElementsOfArray(arrayOfNumbers);
    }

    private static int getLengthOfArray() {
        int length;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please, enter a length of array: ");
        do {
            while (!sc.hasNextInt()) {
                System.out.println("Invalid value entered. Please, try again:");
                sc.next();
            }
            length = sc.nextInt();
            if (length <= 0) {
                System.out.println("You must enter a positive number. Please, try again:");
            }
        } while (length <= 0);
        return length;
    }

    private static double [] getElementsOfArray(int length) {
        double[] arrayOfNumbers = new double[length];
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please, enter an element of array: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            while (!sc.hasNextDouble()) {
                System.out.println("Invalid value entered. Please, try again:");
                sc.next();
            }
            arrayOfNumbers[i] = sc.nextDouble();
        }
        return arrayOfNumbers;
    }

    private static void searchElementsOfArray(double [] arrayOfNumbers) {
        for (double arrayOfNumber : arrayOfNumbers) {
            if (arrayOfNumber % 3 == 0) {
                System.out.print(arrayOfNumber);
                System.out.print(' ');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Код перестаёт работать если перенаправить ввод из файла. Один поток - один сканер. По другому никак.