# Как исправить код по поиску нужного слова "КУБ" с остановкой словом "СТОП"?

Tags: java, строки, scanner

Пользователь вводит слова до тех пор, пока не введёт `СТОП`.
Каждое слово вводится на новой строчке.
Необходимо выяснить, было ли среди введённых слов слово `Куб`.
Если да, то выведите `YES`, если нет, то `NO`.
Через цикл `for` на `java`.

Вот пробовал так написать.
Работает неправильно (нужно 2 раза вводить `стоп` и слово `КУБ` не всегда находит).

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
    
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String n = sc.nextLine();
        boolean is_0 = false;
        for (String a = sc.nextLine()) {
            int a = sc.nextInt();
            if (a.equals("СТОП")) {
                is_0 = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (is_0)
            System.out.println("yes");
        else
            System.out.println("no");
    }
}
```

Comment: Уберите начальный `String n=sc.nextLine();` и строку `int a=sc.nextInt();` внутри цикла (с этой строкой вообще не должно у вас компилироваться, т.к. вы переопределяете существующую переменную в той же области видимости), и по идее все должно заработать

Comment: Этот код даже не ищет слово "КУБ".

Comment: @insolor, для коипилятор не сможет скомпилировать этот цикл `for`, который записан по мотивам цикла `while`

Comment: @NowhereMan, да, точно, на сам for я что-то не обратил внимание. Мельком посмотрел, показалось что там что-то типа `for(String a: итератор)`.

Answer (score 2):

Представленный код содержит массу ошибок:

1. Объявлена строковая переменная `n`, которая нигде не используется, но для которой считывается строка -- то есть, теряется ввод.
2. Цикл `for` записан с ошибкой, так как содержит только часть присваивания без проверки условия и изменения -- см. [базовый туториал](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html), он должен выглядеть так `for (initialization; termination; increment) { statements }`
3. Переменная `a` объявлена дважды, второй раз с типом `int`, но тем не менее сравнивается со словом `"СТОП"`
4. В цикле нигде не проверяется совпадение с требуемым словом `"КУБ"`.

Исправленный код может выглядеть так:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean found = false;
    for (String line = ""; sc.hasNextLine() && !"СТОП".equalsIgnoreCase(line); ) {
        line = sc.nextLine();
        if ("Куб".equalsIgnoreCase(line)) {
            found = true;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(found ? "yes" : "no");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean is_0 = false;
        String string = "";
        while (!string.equals("STOP")) {
            string = sc.nextLine();
            if (string.equals("KYB")) {
                is_0 = true;
            }
        }
        sc.close();
        if (is_0) {
            System.out.println("yes");
        } else {
            System.out.println("no");
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

Перевод с англ на русский реализуйте самостоятельно и другие доработки, если в них есть необходимость (чтение разных регистров итд)
В цикле while проверка на то что строка не равна значению, на котором необходимо цикл остановить. Внутри цикла проверка на равенство строки определенному (искомому) слову.
По окончанию цикла необходимо закрыть сканнер и вывод результата в соответствии с условием (найдено слово в полученных строках или нет)

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Это ответ от Chat GPT что ли?  1) В исходном вопросе требовался цикл `for` 2) Сканер, открытый на стандартном потоке ввода, закрывать НЕ требуется, см. [После `Scanner.close()` как работать со `scanner`?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/721901/), только на днях был [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1550561/).  3) Оператор `return` в конце `main` -- зачем??

Comment: Не понял вопросов. Я на java решаю просто только лишь задачи и не использую на практике этот язык никак. 
В исходном вопросе не написано, что требовался конкретно `for`, я написал тот же цикл, но с `while`.
В чем ошибка закрытия сканнера по окончанию решения задачи, я не очень понял. 
По `return` в конце тоже самое - это просто задача, которая в данном случае может восприниматься как отдельная функция завершенная, в чем ошибка то?

Comment: Наcчёт Сhat GPT похоже погорячился.. :)  Касаемо остального:  1) В тексте вопроса было указано: _Необходимо выяснить, было ли среди введённых слов слово "Куб"...Через цикл for на java._ , поэтому решение через `while` несколько удивило (хотя оно здесь более подходящее) 2) Ошибка с закрытием сканера в том, что этого делать НЕ надо в принципе, когда сканер был создан для `System.in`: если программа закроется, то и сканер закроется тоже. 3) `return` в конце метода `main` просто лишний, о чём приличная IDE выдаст _предупреждение_ `'return' is unnecessary as the last statement in a 'void' method`

Comment: Вроде бы `return 0` требуется в программах на C/C++, где `int main()` возвращает некое целочисленное значение как статус завершения.