# Scanner и System.in: нужно ли закрывать

Tags: java, scanner

Хочу раз и навсегда поставить жирную точку.
**Нужно ли закрывать Scanner, связанный с System.in?**
Ведь если его где-то в программе закрыть, то попытка воспользоваться System.in приведёт к исключению.
В книге Герберта Шилдта закрывается, так же как и у Барри Берда.
В книге Николая Прохоренка не закрывается (по крайней мере, я не заметил).
У Кея Хорстманна вроде бы вообще никакие Scanner напрямую не закрываются, но примерно с середины книги для System.in используется try с ресурсами, который в конечном итоге и закрывает System.in.
Некоторые считают, что System.in открывает не программист, поэтому и закрывать его нечего.
Видел мнение на англоязычном ресурсе, что закрывать System.in категорически нельзя.
А некоторые наоборот считают, что закрывать его необходимо, чтобы освободить ресурсы, но делать это нужно в конце программы.
Некоторые говорят, что закрывать System.in вообще не имеет смысла. А также если есть универсальный код, принимающий на вход InputStream, то System.in нужно заворачивать в декоратор для InputStream, который игнорирует вызов метода close().
Я вообще не понимаю, почему создатели Java не могли проработать такой элементарный вопрос как игнорирование потоком System.in метода close().

Comment: `Scanner` кеширует данные из потока. Даже если вы решите все проблемы с закрытием/незакрытием `System.in`, данные попавшие в кеш `Scanner` вам никто никогда не вернёт. А значит задача не имеет решения. то есть её не надо решать хорошо. Ещё раз: если поток попал в сканнер, данные потока вам больше не принадлежат. Использовать поток вне сканнера бесполезно/бессмысленно.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [2017: После Scanner.close() как работать со scanner?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/721901/)

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy
Не совсем понял. Я после связывания System.in со Scanner могу свободно воспользоваться System.in.read().

Comment: Данный вопрос посвящён наверное второй по популярности проблеме, возникающей при работе со сканером, открытом на системном потоке ввода.  Связанные вопросы (не считая дубля) регулярно появляются на ruSO: [2020 Проблема считывания чисел из консоли](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1065715/); 
[2023 Не записывает данные в файл. Выбрасывает исключение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1486078/); 
[2023 Как исправить: `Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException?`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1550561/) и т.д.  Моё мнение -- `System.in` закрывать НЕ надо.

Comment: Вы подключили `System.in` к `Scanner`. `Scanner` прочитал и закешировал [один килобайт данных](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/util/Scanner.java#L354). Вы можете читать из `System.in`, но вы уже потеряли этот килобайт данных.

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy Я Вас совсем не понимаю. Какой кибибайт данных я потерял, если я ещё ничего не ввёл? Я понимаю, как кэшируются данные из файла, но как закэшировать данные, которых ещё нет? Можно чуточку поподробнее, для новичков?

Comment: Вы не видите кеширования потому что программа читает из входного потока быстрее чем можете в него вводить данные с клавиатуры. Операционная система получает от вас строку и передаёт её в программу. Сканнер пытается прочитать килобайт, но получает одну строку. Если вы перенаправите ввод из файла, вы увидите что пропадают целые строки или их части.

Comment: При вводе с клавиатуры кеширование можно увидеть так: попросите у сканнера одно число, потом прочитайте из потока остаток строки. Запустите программу, введите два числа на одной строке. Второе число исчезнет - вы не запросите его в сканере, но и из потока его не увидеть.

Comment: Вся эта схема у вас "работает" только потому что вы вводите медленно и по одному элементу на строке. Но это тонкий лёд, осторожнее.

Comment: @NowhereMan , этот вопрос не дубль. Читайте внимательно, темы близкие но разные.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, не соглашусь.  Исходный вопрос -- об известной дилемме.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Естественно, второе число исчезнет. Остаток строки считывают тогда, когда хотят избавиться от лишнего мусора, который мог ввести нерадивый пользователь. Если мне нужно ввести два числа из одной строки, то я вызову 2 раза метод `nextInt()`. Или считаю всю строку целиком, а потом на основе этой строки создам ещё один `Scanner` и буду работать со вторым сканнером. Я только что ввёл одной строкой текст около 4 с половиной тыс. символов, а программа считала эту строку и вывела на экран. Всё прекрасно работает, ничего не пропадает.

Comment: @Dyu, демонстрация потери данных при чтении из потока после сканера: https://github.com/StanislavVolodarskiy/scanners.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, если я правильно понял, для чтения данных следует использовать связку `BufferedReader` и `InputStreamReader`?

Comment: @Dyu, можно читать из потока через сканнер (но только один-единственный), можно через `InputStreamReader`. Нельзя их совмещать, всё остальное можно. В моих приложениях (олимпиадные задачи, небольшие утилиты) сканнер удобнее всего. Но сканнер должен быть один и нельзя обращаться к потоку напрямую после создания сканнера.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, я не понимаю, что толку от `BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));`, если данные так же пропадают, как и со `Scanner`?

Comment: @Dyu, вы правильно понимаете. Если вы надели на поток обёртку с буфером, вы не должны больше пользоваться потоком напрямую или передавать поток другим обёрткам. По этой причине в C++ буфер - часть самого потока, не дополнительная обёртка.

Comment: @Dyu, как вы сами теперь ответите на ваш изначальный вопрос?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, закрывать `System.in` не надо. После подключения его к объекту, читающему с использованием буфера, нельзя передавать этот поток другим объектам. Если потребуется работать с `System.in` с использованием нескольких объектов, буду пользоваться собственным классом с использованием `System.in.read()`. Хотя, изобретать велосипед, наверно, не надо. Что-то подобное наверняка уже создали до меня. С чтением файлов не совсем понял, можно ли пользоваться несколькими объектами, использующими один и тот же файл?

Comment: @Dyu, всё так. Велосипедов два: если вам нужен форматированный ввод, вы надеваете на поток сканнер. Если нужен неформатированный ввод, надеваете на поток `BufferedReader(InputStreamReader())`. Если надо совмещать, надеваете буфер, нарезаете на строки, отдельные строки передаёте отдельным сканнерам (это безопасно).